# Autocomplete does nothing. What is wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, autocomplete

I have autocomplete code which does not work.

I have input field class Coordinate where when i type code it finds value from my DB that matches with geo_code and hence finds the input code country.

So when i type `UK` it matches with  `geo_code` and then matches the last with the `country` so in this case UK is code i type it can be found in geo_code and country is United Kingdom. The code works, what i want to achieve is bring autocomplete to give suggestions while typing. for examples:

```
UK   United Kingdom
USA  United States of America
```

What i did so far:

In **models.py** i have:

```
class Coordinate(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Profiles(models.Model):
    geocode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='profiles_country'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.geocode)
```

in **forms.py**:

```
from dal import autocomplete

class CoordinateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    code= forms.CharField(max_length=150, label='',widget= forms.TextInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Coordinate
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'code': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='coordinate-autocomplete')}
```

in **views.py**:

```
class CoordinateAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
        def get_queryset(self):
            if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                return Profiles.objects.none()
            qs = Profiles.objects.all()
            if self.q:
                qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
            return qs
```

in **base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'geoproj/css/main.css' %}">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div>{% block content %}{% endblock  %} 

         {% block javascripts %} {% endblock %} </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

in **geo.html** :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form}}
                    {{form.media }}
            <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button></form>


{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}

{% block javascripts %} {% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate you help to solve this case.

Comment: Hello mate, why don't you use javascript? In my knowledge you can't do that only with django because is a front-end issue, the back-end does not handle with the data while is not send to it. I hope this helps you, stay safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py:

```
class Coordinate(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Profiles(models.Model):
    geocode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='profiles_country'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.geocode)
```

views.py:

```
def geoview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #do your operations
        return render(request, 'result.html')

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def getgeocode(request, geocode):
    results = Coordinate.objects.filter(code__istartswith=str(geocode))
    sendres = ""
    for resn in results[:10]:
        sendres += "<option class='bg-primary'>" + resn.code + "</option>"
    return HttpResponse(sendres)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="text" list="mylist" name="geocodes" id="geocodes" placeholder="enter geocde"
               onkeyup="getGeoCode(this.value)" autocomplete="off"/>
        <datalist id="mylist">
        </datalist>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        function getGeoCode(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("mylist").style.border = "0px";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/coordinate-autocomplete/" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('geo/', views.geoview, name='geo'),
    path('coordinate-autocomplete/<geocode>', views.getgeocode, name='coordinate-autocomplete'),
    ....
]
```

[image]

[image]

and you can confirm its working in your terminal you will see get request like:
`/coordinate-autocomplete/{word_in_iput}`

```
[17/Apr/2020 16:19:52] "GET /coordinate-autocomplete/u HTTP/1.1" 200 120
[17/Apr/2020 16:20:03] "GET /coordinate-autocomplete/us HTTP/1.1" 200 65
[17/Apr/2020 16:20:06] "GET /coordinate-autocomplete/u HTTP/1.1" 200 120
[17/Apr/2020 16:20:13] "GET /coordinate-autocomplete/i HTTP/1.1" 200 44
```

Comment: It is not asnwer. A valid answer bases on the code i wrote above in the question.

Comment: @Günel do you want autocomplete to work with using django form without using javasript?

Comment: I'm on mobile now so not able to send well formatted code but here's something you can do... Add autocomplete:false  like : `attrs={ 'theme': 'bootstrap','autocomplete':'false'}` in attr of form

Comment: This will disable suggesting cached value in browser

Comment: After some time I will post some code with javascript and ajax I'm sure that will work

Comment: I have sent link in the chat room

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the js that links the URL response and HTML template. Here how I will solve it. Provided your view works.
You will generate the suggestion by

1. First Creating a js event listener to get text from the input box of the
   form
2. Once you get this text you will do an ajax call to the view URL
   you have mention
3. After you get ajax result you will then create a for
   loop and generate select tags for the input.

This is how I would write the js code to communicate with the Html template and Django autocomplete view URL.

Comment: it is not my question. I know what is static files my question specifically links to Autocomplete and how to combine with js, what code to insert in my case as others did not work for me.

Comment: Sorry about that but you you please update your question to reflect the exact code, view, and model. It is unclear what you are trying to say. Autocomplete of what @Günel

Comment: Ohh okay, now I understand.

Comment: So where are you now, did you put the JS in script tags as they did in the example. What happened after that?

Comment: Does this help you get an idea? @Günel

Comment: It would be too much to give you code in this post, we can chat in one of the rooms and I can tell you line by line what you need to do. It is exact same processor I mentioned above but in js code.

Comment: @Günel check the last  part where I shared the complete code you would eventually modify

Answer (score 0):

**`code`** field in the *CoordinateForm* is ***CharField***, not ***ModelChoiceField***, so it fails to work correctly with QuerySet returned by autocomplete.

Comment: ModelChoiceField gives dropdown menu - it is not what i want